# Can %r pattern in log4j 2 be correctly used in combination with Java application servers (Payara4.1)?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, payara

I am trying out log4j 2 to improve the logging in my project. I am using a RollingFile appender that creates a log file every day.

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">D:/logs/</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/daily.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/daily_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%-5level: %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %c{1}::%M -  [%X{username}] %m [%r]%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5level: %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %c{1}::%M - [%X{username}] %m [%r]%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
    <!-- Change logging level below. Accepted values: error, warning, info, debug, trace -->
    <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now I have a question about the %r pattern. This should respresent the number of milliseconds elapsed from the construction of the layout until the creation of the logging event.

When I was running this, I noticed the milliseconds being way to high, only increasing in number. This has to do with the reuse of threads by the Java Application server (in my case Payara 4.1).

Is there any way around this so that I can get the milliseconds for the request itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%r represents the number of milliseconds since the JVM started, not necessarily when the Layout was created. The value is calculated by calling ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime(); when the pattern converter is created and then subtracting the event timestamp from the start time value for each event. Given that the start time never changes this value should grow over time as you are describing.

Log4j doesn't have any way to get the time the request was started. You could capture that in a ThreadContext value and then create your own pattern converter to use that value as the value to subtract from the current system time.

Comment: Thank you for clearifying that out. I did what you suggested and subtracted the 2 values to get the millis.